# Foreign key issue : (3780, "Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint)

Tags: sql, mysql, django, django-models

In my django website I have a user model :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = "myapp"
```

The issue is when I try to create a simple other model referencing to the User model :

```
class TestTable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

I get this error when trying to migrate after makemigrations :

> (3780, "Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in
> foreign key constraint

I think the issue is about the type of the "id" in user table and "user_id" in test table, when I describe the tables with SQL commands I get this :

```
mysql> describe myapp_user;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username     | varchar(150) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name   | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(254) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this :

```
mysql> describe myapp_testtable;
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value   | double | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | bigint | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see there is *int* and *bigint* types.

Why does this happen?
How can I simply fix this issue without doing weird stuff?

Comment: I pricise that I didnt get this issue when I created other tables in the past. I dont get why I get this error now and not before (I didnt change any settings in my sql database server)

Comment: It would be helpful if you published the outcome of show create table for both tables that way we can see things like engine which isn't shown by describe.

Comment: Anyway,, bigint is not compatible with int presumably because bigint can be much larger than int . Also it isn't logical to have a bigint column referencing int. https://dbfiddle.uk/d5UldwUJ